# How get entries by sources in a frontend fieldlayout?

Tags: field, frontend, sources

I have multiple entries fields that I want to use in the front-end. In the field settings I'll set up a sections source for each field. On the frontend I want a dropdown select box with all the entries from section I'll setup for each entries field. If I'll dump the field sources from the field layout I'll get this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(44) "section:a0977adf3fd-bd50adf-479cadf-90cd-8d5ef46de79c"
}
```

How to get entries related to the section source above?

```
{% entries = craft.entries.section(field.sources).all() %} // This is not working
```

This is the code where I'll need it for some context

```
{% for tab in entry.fieldLayout.tabs %}
    {{ tab.name }}
    {% for field in tab.getFields() %}
            <label for="{{ field.handle }}">{{ field.name }}</label>
            {% if field.className == 'craft\\fields\\PlainText' %}
                {# field text settings #}
            {% elseif field.className == 'craft\\fields\\Number' %}
                {# field number settings #}
            {% elseif field.className == 'craft\\fields\\Entries' %}
                {% set entries = craft.entries.section(field.sources).all() %} 
                {# entries is empty how to fix? #}
                <select name="fields[{{ field.handle }}][]">
                    <option value="">Choose</option>
                    {% for entry in entries %}
                        <option value="{{ entry.id }}">{{ entry.title }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIDs are not yet usable in queries. You would need to extract the `UID` of the section from the string then fetch the `sectionId` to use in your query.

Something like this:

```twig
{% for tab in entry.fieldLayout.tabs %}
    {{ tab.name }}
    {% for field in tab.getFields() %}
        <label for="{{ field.handle }}">{{ field.name }}</label> <br>
        {% if field.className == 'craft\\fields\\PlainText' %}
        {# field text settings #}
        {% elseif field.className == 'craft\\fields\\Number' %}
        {# field number settings #}
        {% elseif field.className == 'craft\\fields\\Entries' %}

            {% set sources = [] %}

            {# Start our `entries` query #}
            {% set entries = craft.entries %}

            {# Iterate over sources #}
            {% for source in field.sources %}

                {# If All sources is selected in field definition, skip this #}
                {% if source != '*' %}
                    {# Extract UID from the string #}
                    {% set sectionUid = source | replace({'section:': ''}) %}

                    {# Fetch sectionId from UID and push in `sources` array #}
                    {% set sources = sources | merge([craft.app.sections.getSectionByUid(sectionUid).id]) %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {# If we have `sources` then add to our query, else, fetch everything #}
            {% set entries = sources ? entries.sectionId(sources) : entries %}
            <select name="fields[{{ field.handle }}][]">
                <option value="">Choose</option>
                {% for entry in entries.all() %}
                    <option value="{{ entry.id }}">{{ entry.title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will cater for multiple sources as well as *All* being chosen in your field definition